# run flutter project on iPhone 15 simulator ON M1 MAC

Tags: flutter, macos, simulator

I have an **M1 Mac**, I want to run my project on the iPhone 15 pro max simulator, I got an error.

```
Error (Xcode): DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.
```

I googled and some guys suggested to add these lines to podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
 xcode_base_version = `xcodebuild -version | grep 'Xcode' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d . -f 1`

  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
      config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
      config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"

      config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
      # For xcode 15+ only
       if config.base_configuration_reference && Integer(xcode_base_version) >= 15
          xcconfig_path = config.base_configuration_reference.real_path
          xcconfig = File.read(xcconfig_path)
          xcconfig_mod = xcconfig.gsub(/DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR/, "TOOLCHAIN_DIR")
          File.open(xcconfig_path, "w") { |file| file << xcconfig_mod }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

when I am running I get this error:

```
Warning: CocoaPods is installed but broken. Skipping pod install.
  You appear to have CocoaPods installed but it is not working.
  This can happen if the version of Ruby that CocoaPods was installed with is different from the one being used to invoke it.
  This can usually be fixed by re-installing CocoaPods.
To re-install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

CocoaPods not installed or not in valid state.
Error launching application on iPhone 15 Pro Max.
```

I installed cocoapods again:

```
 ios % brew install cocoapods           
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
#=#=-  #       #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
######################################################################################################################################################################################################################################################### 100.0%
Warning: Treating cocoapods as a formula. For the cask, use homebrew/cask/cocoapods
Warning: cocoapods 1.14.2 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.14.2, run:
  brew reinstall cocoapods
 ios %
```

when I am trying to install with gem I get this error:

```
ios % sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
        There are no versions of cocoapods-downloader (>= 2.0) compatible with your Ruby & RubyGems. Maybe try installing an older version of the gem you're looking for?
        cocoapods-downloader requires Ruby version >= 2.7.4. The current ruby version is 2.7.2.137.
```

but by **brew** everything is ok.

```
 ios % gem which cocoapods                                                                                                   
/Users/alt/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/cocoapods-1.13.0/lib/cocoapods.rb
```

my pod version :

```
 pod --version                    
1.12.1
```

Gemfile:

```
gem "Fastlane"
gem "colorize"
gem 'cocoapods', '~> 1.12.1'
gem 'activesupport', '~> 7.0.8'
gem "fileutils"
gem "base64"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same error

Error (Xcode): `DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR` cannot be used to evaluate `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS`, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 15.

This is what I found [Here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737795)